# What can set id property to null when mock saving method

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking, mockito

Testing with Mockito my API, found very strange thing to me. Creating new User with id property not null, invoke mock of save(user) and getting user.id is null. "Real" save method works different, it saves entity and sets it's id property to unique long value, not null.
Code service layer:

```
@Override
public Long save(User user) {
    userDao.save(user);
    return user.getId();
}
```

Controller of API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody String addUser(@RequestBody String jsonString) {
    User user = User.fromJson(jsonString);
    userService.save(user);
    return user.toJson();
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
public void addUser() throws Exception {
    Role role = new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER");
    User user = new User (1L, "Test user", "Test password", true,  role);
    when(roleService.findByName(role.getName())).thenReturn(role);
    when(userService.save(user)).thenReturn(1L);

    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/user").content(user.toJson())).andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
        .andReturn();

    assertEquals(user.toJson(), result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    verify(userService).save(user);
}
```

which never passed because expected user with id=1 and actual is user with id=null.
Please help find which thing can set user.id to null?
Once again, service method (and dao) save works perfect.

ADDED:
Dao code:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Comment: Is there an `equals` method in your `User` class?  If not, Mockito can't know that the `User` you stubbed with matches the `User` extracted from the JSON String.

Comment: Sure, there is. I'm checking change of user.id by debugging, it sets to null when save method in controller invoked.

Comment: OK, does it return `true` when matching the `User` that you created in your test with the `User` that's extracted from the JSON string?

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with the ID returned from `userService.save(user)`. You've mocked the return from the method, but that doesn't have any effect on the `user` object.

Comment: Yes, David, I have tested my json methods already, works fine. Class - Json - Class. Anyway how it can be connected with id changing?

Comment: May help to show what `userDao.save(user);` actually does

Comment: Yes, JonK, but as you see I've set id to 1L when created new User, and problem is user.id = null after save method invoked in controller.

Comment: I'm asking that, because you wrote `when(userService.save(user)).thenReturn(1L);`, which uses the `equals` method of your `User` class to compare the `user` that's passed in to `save` at the "Act" phase of the test with the `user` that's passed in at the "Arrange" phase.  If `equals` doesn't return true for these two different `User` objects, the stubbing will have no effect.

Comment: can you try when(userService.save(anyObject())).thenReturn(1L);  instead? good luck

Comment: Looking at the test method, I see what appears to be an obvious mistake: data for the new `User` is created *with* an id, when it should have none (`null`, in this case). The id is only acquired once the user is saved.